# how to design a blog. using html css javascript and backend services

Tags: flutter, web, frontend, backend, blogs

I have started web development, I have used WordPress but I want to code my own blog, but I don't know where to start, Can someone guide me as to which technologies I should use, what things I should learn, and what steps to follow. please do mentions how I can build good UI, and what are the things that require backend services. Can I make my blog totally on the frontend? I just want to have articles in it.  furthermore, I am also learning to make an app from flutter so I am wanting to make a blog app for the website too (like connecting them).
What is the use of backend in such blogs, and how much to do?. Is an API needed.
I hope you can suggest to me some ideas.

please be simple and clear as possible.

Comment: If you want to use Flutter, then you will have both an app for iOS and Android and a website. You don't have to do the backend yourself, you can uses Firebase services. They offer you authentication (with many providers: email/password, Google, Facebook, Apple Microsoft), a database (Firestore), cloud storage (Firebase Storage), notifications and many other services... Please note that Firebase is a BaaS, backend as a service and they do have a free plan, after run out off the free plan you can always pay for me. The free plan is decent and you can have many thousands of users until paying.

Comment: thanks for helping me, what I was interested in was how to make a blog by coding it all the way. n how to apply backend services to it.

Comment: Look up Flutter Firebase tutorials.